# Calling sub repeatedly after printing data, old data staying in cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a label I'm printing out using Excel VBA.  You click LOOKUP and it runs the FINDSAL() sub.

The person scans a barcode or manually enters a 6 digit number.  The 6 digit number is checked against a "RawData" worksheet within the workbook to validate it exists.  It then uses vlookup functions to compile the Name, City, state, PONumber and update the fields.  It then asks how many labels and prints out the corresponding amount.  It then calls FINDSAL() again so they don't have to keep clicking the LOOKUP button and can go onto the next order.

The issue I'm having is it inconsistently prints the next order.  It'll update the order number and print but has the previous orders name, city, state, PO, etc.

I've tried using `Application.ScreenUpdating = True)` (and False) in different places but it has not been effective.  In the past I've tried using a timer of 5 seconds but it seems everything runs too fast and isn't running each step until completion.

Any method to do this?

[image: Label]

**Code:**

```
Sub FINDSAL()

Dim OrderNumber As String
Dim ReturnValue As String
Dim Weight As String
Dim NumberPallets As String
Dim ShipName As String
Dim CustPO As String
Dim TotalPalletWeight As String

    OrderNumber = ""
    NumberPallets = ""
    Weight = ""
    
    'Reset all of the text box values so you know you're not getting values from previous orders.

    WorkSheets(1).OrderNumberBox.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).ShipNameBoxLarge.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).PalletNumber1.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).PalletNumber2.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).CustomerPOBox.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).Barcode.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).NeworInvoiced.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).WeightBox.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).City.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).State.Value = ""

    'Error check.  If order number is longer than 6 characters we know it's wrong at this point.
    While Len(OrderNumber) < 6 Or Len(OrderNumber) > 6
      OrderNumber = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Order Number", Title:="Order Number")
      If OrderNumber = "" Then Exit Sub
      If OrderNumber = False Then Exit Sub
    Wend
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
            
            'Search RawData tab for value to check validity
            Dim SearchRange As range
            Dim lRow As Long
            Dim aRng As range, rngFnd As range
            Dim myFnd As String
           
            myFnd = OrderNumber 'Need to trim it because there are the padded spaces.
            
            If myFnd = "" Then
                Exit Sub
              ElseIf IsNumeric(myFnd) Then
                myFnd = Val(myFnd) '/ converts a "text" number to a value
              Else
                '/ is text and that is okay
            End If
            
            With Sheets("RawData")
                Set rngFnd = Sheets("RawData").range("A:F").Find(What:=myFnd, _
                                 LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
                
                'Order number is found - valid order number
                If Not rngFnd Is Nothing Then
                      WorkSheets(1).OrderNumberBox.Value = OrderNumber
                      WorkSheets(1).Barcode.Value = "*" & OrderNumber & "*"
                      WorkSheets(1).ShipNameBoxLarge.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngFnd, Sheets("Rawdata").range("A:F"), 2, False)
                      WorkSheets(1).City.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngFnd, Sheets("Rawdata").range("A:F"), 3, False)
                      WorkSheets(1).State.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngFnd, Sheets("Rawdata").range("A:F"), 4, False)
                      WorkSheets(1).CustomerPOBox.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngFnd, Sheets("Rawdata").range("A:F"), 5, False)

                    
                      Dim Invoiced As String
                      Invoiced = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngFnd, Sheets("Rawdata").range("A:F"), 6, False)
                      WorkSheets(1).NeworInvoiced.Value = Invoiced
                      
                      If Invoiced = "INVOICED" Then
                          Dim InvoicedAnswer As Integer
                          InvoicedAnswer = MsgBox("This order has already been invoiced/shipped and may be a duplicate." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Continue printing?", vbExclamation + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Already invoiced/shipped")
                      
                               If InvoicedAnswer = vbNo Then
                                  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                                  InvoiceAnswer = ""
                                  WorkSheets(1).OrderNumberBox.Value = ""
                                  WorkSheets(1).ShipNameBoxLarge.Value = ""
                                  WorkSheets(1).PalletNumber1.Value = ""
                                  WorkSheets(1).PalletNumber2.Value = ""
                                  WorkSheets(1).CustomerPOBox.Value = ""
                                  WorkSheets(1).Barcode.Value = ""
                                  WorkSheets(1).NeworInvoiced.Value = ""
                                  WorkSheets(1).WeightBox.Value = ""
                                  WorkSheets(1).City.Value = ""
                                  WorkSheets(1).State.Value = ""

                                  GoTo EndOfSub
                               End If
                               
                     End If
                      
                      Else
                        MsgBox "Order not found"
                        WorkSheets(1).OrderNumberBox.Value = "Not Found" '10/17/2018
                        Call FINDSAL 'Loop back to the lookup box.
                        Exit Sub
                      End If

              End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'How many pallets -- Placed this down here because if they order number is incorrect or not found no point in wasting time entering how many pallets.
      NumberPallets = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="How many lables do you need?", Title:="How many lables do you need?", Type:=1)
         If NumberPallets = "" Then Exit Sub
         If NumberPallets = False Then Exit Sub
          
        Dim answer As String
        
        If NumberPallets >= 30 Then
          MsgBox ("Over label limit:  " & NumberPallets & "." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Print 2 sets if you need more than 30.")
          Exit Sub
        End If
    
        If NumberPallets > 10 Then
          answer = MsgBox("You entered " & NumberPallets & " labels.  Is this correct?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation)
          If answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        End If
    
    
        'NEED THIS FOR REPRINT FUNCTION - Number of pallets total...2nd pallet box.
        WorkSheets(1).PalletNumber2.Value = NumberPallets
            
        printCount = 0 'Used to keep a count of how many pages have printed.
    
        'Print Label
        Call SetPrintArea
        Debug.Print "A:  " & PrinterPort
        Sheets(1).PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=NumberPallets, Preview:=False, Collate:=False
        i = i + 1
        printCount = printCount + 1
    
        'Sets the previous order for reprint.
        WorkSheets(1).PreviousOrderNumber.Value = OrderNumber
        

EndOfSub:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Reset all the boxes for next label
    InvoiceAnswer = ""
    WorkSheets(1).OrderNumberBox.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).ShipNameBoxLarge.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).PalletNumber1.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).PalletNumber2.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).CustomerPOBox.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).Barcode.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).NeworInvoiced.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).WeightBox.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).City.Value = ""
    WorkSheets(1).State.Value = ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Call FINDSAL

    Exit Sub



'If there is any errors just say the order is not found.

ErrorHandler:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    'Workbooks(LookupBookName).Close False
    MsgBox "Order number not found:  " & Trim(OrderNumber)
    Err.Clear

Else
    'Workbooks(LookupBookName).Close False
    
End If
  

End Sub
```

**Update** with debugging attempts.  I went ahead and declared the values as strings and set the `vlookup` functions as the `variable` then update the value of the TextBox to the `variable`.

The debug printouts are correct and have the correct information.  For whatever reason the Worksheet values aren't updating except for the order number box and is the only one not a vlookup.

```
'Update worksheet boxes.
WorkSheets(1).OrderNumberBox.Value = OrderNumber
WorkSheets(1).Barcode.Value = "*" & OrderNumber & "*"
                  
Dim ShipNameBoxLarge As String
Dim City As String
Dim State As String
Dim CustomerPOBox As String

ShipNameBoxLarge = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngFnd, Sheets("Rawdata").range("A:F"), 2, False)
City = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngFnd, Sheets("Rawdata").range("A:F"), 3, False)
State = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngFnd, Sheets("Rawdata").range("A:F"), 4, False)
CustomerPOBox = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngFnd, Sheets("Rawdata").range("A:F"), 5, False)

WorkSheets(1).ShipNameBoxLarge.Value = ShipNameBoxLarge
WorkSheets(1).City.Value = City
WorkSheets(1).State.Value = State
WorkSheets(1).CustomerPOBox.Value = CustomerPOBox
WorkSheets(1).NeworInvoiced.Value = Invoiced

Debug.Print OrderNumber
Debug.Print ShipNameBoxLarge
Debug.Print City
Debug.Print State
Debug.Print CustomerPOBox
Debug.Print Invoiced
Debug.Print "----------"
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding a breakpoint to the 'Set rngFnd =' line as, with already-used details appearing against new order numbers, it suggests that the Vlookup code isn't running in those circumstances

Comment: It sounds like there are multiple instances of an order number, each having a different address. You want to print a label for each address associated with that order number?  If this is the case, I would create a routine that captures all the addresses and returns a single `Collection` of those addresses. Then loop through the `Collection` and print each one. That separates the barcode scan/user input step from the address search from the printing and gives you more control.

Comment: @PeterT Single order number.  Just need the first one it finds.

Comment: @SpectralInstance updated with some debug info.  The vlookup is running according to `debug.prints`

Comment: If your controls are standard TextBoxes, have you tried targeting their Text properties instead of Value ?
Also, just for debugging purposes, consider disabling all your Application.ScreenUpdating = False lines

Comment: @SpectralInstance I did.  I changed all the `.value` to `.text` and same result.  I also removed all the `Application.ScreenUpdating` lines and set it to `true` at the beginning of the sub.

Comment: Ok, then stepping through the code, after you see that a variable HAS been updated by the vlookup function, and AFTER the line that assigns that variable to the text/value property of the control (but the control doesn't update), how about pausing there and, in the Immediate Window, trying directly to update the text/value property with the value of the variable?

Comment: @SpectralInstance the immediate window shows the correct value already.  I went so far as to put in `MsgBox` and I'm watching the correct value in the message box it just never sets the value of the textbox.  It'll do it AFTER you click cancel when it re-runs the sub though.  So it's setting everything correct, just will not re-update the textbox on the next run.

Comment: Ok, try putting in a DoEvents call, AFTER the Vlookups have run but BEFORE you assign the  variables to the value/text fields of the controls (and maybe experiment by having one DoEvents for each control, i.e. VLOOKUP -> DoEvents -> assign VLOOKUP result)

Comment: @SpectralInstance That definitely helped.  I had to do it before every vlookup and every `.value` change.  It doesn't ALWAYS update the screen BUT it does PRINT correctly which is fine for me.  That's the goal.

Comment: It was the 'connection' to the barcode scanner that prompted me to think of that - maybe it could be put on 'standby' between scans, or maybe the issue arises less if orders are all manually entered

Comment: @SpectralInstance Ironically I was hand keying them all manually.  We have noticed int he past CPU speed does influence whether it updates so I think that "pause" that's occuring with DoEvents is just enough to work.

Comment: Just had another idea - from the visual perspective, maybe `UserFormName.Repaint` might also have an effect ?